# My controller does not work unless plugged in with a USB cable

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers

My PS4 controller is connected to my PC with Bluetooth. The controller works with some games that I downloaded on Steam: when I turn it on the controller has a blue light and allows me to play as much as I want.

However, I downloaded a game off of a website and my controller only seems to work when it is plugged in with a USB cable. I've tried countless times to pair my controller via Bluetooth but while it says the controller is connected, the controller doesn't stay on for more than 5 seconds before automatically turning off again.

How do I keep my PS4 controller connected wirelessly? I'm using an *Alienware Aurora* gaming PC.

Answer (score 4):

To access all the functionality of a DS4 on Windows you need a driver. Steam has an internal driver that supports Playstation controllers. If you add your game to Steam as a "Non-Steam Game" then it can use Steam's DS4 controller support.

Alternatively, you can use unofficial third-party drivers like DS4Windows that create a virtual XInput device for use with non-Steam games that need XInput.

Comment: This. I've written scripts for controller support, before, and PS4 controllers even need special considerations compared to just about every other controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was running a PowerA XBox controller. I run a custom build with a 3060ti and an i7 9700f on Windows 10. I just downloaded drivers and it fixed that. If you have a controller that is not made by Sony, I suggest to go to the website and check that you have all of the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The internal battery may be dead. To test this out, try the controller on a PlayStation 4 console, and see if it still shuts down after 5 seconds. This seems like an obvious answer, but working in technical support, I can tell you that even we miss the little things from time to time.

---

The immediate solution is to plug it in and let it charge. It sounds like your already naturally doing this; *however*, you could also be at the end of the battery lifetime. Rechargeable batteries don't last forever, and multiple causes can lead to a lower battery life. At first, the battery may only last half the time it did when the controller was brand new. Eventually, the battery will only give you a few seconds of life, before completely cutting out.

---

***What can I do to prevent this from happening?***

This is inevitably going to happen. We are not at the technological stage where rechargeable batteries last forever. There are a few things you can do to prolong the lifetime of the battery:

1. Let the controller completely discharge before plugging it back in to recharge.
2. Let the controller completely recharge before unplugging and/or playing with it.
3. *<del>Do not let your controller continue charging once it has reached its maximum battery capacity</del>* This last rule generally applies to rechargeable batteries, so I'm leaving it here for reference; however, numerous sources <sup>[1](https://www.thegamingman.com/can-a-ps4-controller-overcharge/) [2](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-bad-to-charge-your-PS4-controller-while-playing) [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/1so40z/will_leaving_the_dualshock_4_plugged_in_to_the/)</sup> have confirmed that the controller is designed to stop charging at maximum capacity. In other words, the controller will do this step for you on its own.

***What can I do if I confirm my controllers rechargeable battery has completely died?***

If this does turn out to be the issue, there are four possible solutions you can consider:

1. If the controller is still under warranty, you can reach out to either Sony or the store where the controller was purchased for a replacement.
2. If the controller is not under warranty, you can still reach out to Sony (and sometimes the store where the controller was purchased - always worth checking) for a repair. This will likely cost you; and sometimes, the cost of repair significantly outweighs the cost for replacement.
3. Replace the controller. If the controller does not have any sentimental value, this might be a cheaper alternative than paying for a repair.
4. Replace the battery. This is by far the cheapest solution, outside of warranty, but may require a bit of technical expertise on your side. There is always a risk of further damage to the controller, which will also void any warranty claim. *Only do this if you know what your doing and the warranty has already run out on the controller*.

***How do I replace the internal battery?***

[There is a great guide for this at ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/DualShock+4+Battery+Replacement/22074), complete with step by step images. I also found this video, on YouTube: